# HTTP DELETE verb in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, rest, express

Do I need to set up any configuration before I can make DELETE requests to a node.js application?

I can make `GET`, `POST` or `PUT` requests, but `DELETE` requests won't work.

`DELETE http://localhost:8081/api/1.0/entry` yields `undefined` from the routing logger, I'm using express to register the routes. But it looks like I can't even resolve the url / verb.

This is how I'm invoking it:

```
rows.find('a.remove').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/1.0/entry',
        type: 'DELETE'
    }).done(function(res){
        var row = $(this).parentsUntil('tbody');
        row.slideUp();
    });
});
```

Sample log

```
GET / 200 18ms  
GET /author/entry 200 10ms  
GET /api/1.0/entry 200 2ms  
GET /api/1.0/entry 200 1ms  
GET /api/1.0/entry 200 1ms  
undefined
```

Comment: No configuration needed in express... just use app.delete('/api/1.0/entry', function (req, res){

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be `.del`?

Comment: True... you can use .del too. Have always used .delete.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome edge, why? I can see in the console the request being fired, it just never arrives at the server

Comment: @Nico The jQuery docs claim that some browsers won't send PUT/DELETE ajax reqs properly.  That should work fine, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hopefully this can help:

- **Enable logging as your first middleware to make sure the request is coming in:**

  `app.use(express.logger());`
- **Use the methodOverride() middleware:**

  `app.use(express.bodyParser());`

  `app.use(express.methodOverride()); // looks for DELETE verbs in hidden fields`
- **Create a .del() route:**

  `app.del('/api/1.0/entry', function(req, res, next) { ... });`

Comment: logging is enabled, but when the request comes in, I get `undefined` as the route, which is really weird

Comment: I think it would be *really* helpful if you could post your (relevant) server-side code ...

Comment: If `undefined` is the route, then the problem is client-side, not server-side. Express will not match `undefined` to `/api/1.0/entry`.

Comment: but I get `undefined` before the routing middleware, in the `express.logger`, see the OP for a sample list

Comment: I agree with Golo, it would be useful to see the relevant server-side code. Especially the middleware stack. It would also be a good idea for you to make a minimal server that only has the one DELETE route to debug. Do you have the methodOverride() middleware in the stack?

Comment: stupidly enough, the incident was my route didn't have a `res.end()`

Comment: @hunterloftis Since express does not longer support both `express.bodyParser` and `express.methodOverride` (not much changed, you just have to install those by npm now), you might want to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

PUT and DELETE values for **type** setting are not supported by all browsers:

See documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can use POST type including **data:{_method:'delete'}** in ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    data:{_method:'delete'},
    url: '/api/1.0/entry',
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(res){
    var row = $(this).parentsUntil('tbody');
    row.slideUp();
});
```

Comment: All contemporary browsers support them.