# Using the PUT method with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I'm trying to implement update functionality to an Express.js app, and I'd like to use a PUT request to send the new data, but I keep getting errors using PUT.  From everything I've read, it's just a matter of using app.put, but that isn't working.  I've got the following in  my routes file:

```
send = function(req, res) { 
    req.send(res.locals.content);
};

app.put('/api/:company', function(res,req) {
    res.send('this is an update');
}, send);
```

When I use postman to make a PUT request, I get a "cannot PUT /api/petshop" as an error.  I don't understand why I can't PUT, or what's going wrong.

Comment: what error show in postman, 500? 404?

Comment: Have you tried using methodOverride()? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378414/918608 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14174177/918608

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may be lacking the actual update function. You have the put path returning the result back to the client but missing the part when you tell the database to update the data.

If you're using MongoDB and ExpressJS, you could write something like this :

```
app.put('/api/:company', function (req, res) {
    var company = req.company;
    company = _.extend(company, req.body);
    company.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send('/company', {
            errors: err.errors,
            company: company
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(company);
    }   
  })
});
```

This [mean stack project](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) may help you as it covers this CRUD functionality which I just used here swapping their articles for your companies. same same.

Comment: are the `req` and `res` arguments in the callback in the wrong order? Should be `function(req,res)`? http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.put.method

Comment: @Akurn, yes should be req res.

Answer (score 5):

Your callback function has the arguments in the wrong order.

Change the order of callback to `function(req, res)`.
Don't use `function(res, req)`.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to redirect in `put` or `delete` (to `get` adress), you can't use normal `res.redirect('/path')`, you should use `res.redirect(303, '/path')` instead. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33215327/4718434))

If not, you'll get `Cannot PUT` error.

Answer (score -6):

Have you been checking out your headers information? 
Because header should be `header['content-type'] = 'application/json';` then only you will get the update object in server side (node-express), otherwise if you have content type plain 'text/htm' like that you will get `empty req.body` in your node app.