# How do I retrieve the route in app.put()?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, put

I am trying to write a function similar to this one documented here ([Using the PUT method with Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601922/using-the-put-method-with-express-js#21395174)), but am failing.

In this example, I need to retrieve the value in  :company  What I am getting is `undefined`

I tried many variations including

```
var company = req.company;
```

```
var company = JSON.stringify(req.company);
```

```
var company = req.company[0];
```

Thus far, all have yielded the same result. What is the correct syntax?

```
app.put('/api/:company', function (req, res) {
    var company = req.company;

    company = _.extend(company, req.body);

    company.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send('/company', {
            errors: err.errors,
            company: company
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(company);
    }

});
```

UPDATE:
Per the suggestion of @Robot, I have also tried

```
var company = req.param.company 

and 

console.log(req.param)
```

the second is the closest i have gotten to an answer with

```
[function param]
```

Additional testing:
let foo = req.param;
then
foo()
yields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;params&#39; of undefined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at param (/home/w/node_modules/express/lib/request.js:236:21)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at app.put (/home/w/server.js:195:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/w/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/home/w/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (/home/w/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/w/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/w/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at param (/home/w/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at param (/home/w/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/home/w/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

FIX:
Thanks to @AmIDeranged and this tutorial https://www.robinwieruch.de/node-express-server-rest-api

you can use either

```
req.params.company
```

or

```
${req.params.company}
```

I am not certain what the ${} adds to the conversation, but that is left for another day(!!!)

Comment: Try req.params.company - not req.param.company.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I was just going to say that I fixed it with the help of this tutorial as well   https://www.robinwieruch.de/node-express-server-rest-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AmIDeranged and this tutorial https://www.robinwieruch.de/node-express-server-rest-api

you can use either

```
req.params.company
```

or

```
${req.params.company}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.put('/api/:company', handler);
```

sending request to `/api/abcCompany`, `req.param.company` would return `abcCompany`

noting will be in `req.company` unless you write your own middleware which can fill the `req.company` to pass it to other middlewares

you have access to company data in `req.param.company`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am still getting something wrong. since the route (represented in :company) is a string, I am trying to print it using console.log(company) => undefined and console.log(req.params) =>[Function: param].  What am I misunderstanding?